# Why is nvlink warning me about lack of sm_20 (compute capability 2.0) object code?

Tags: cuda, linker, compute-capability, nvlink

I'm working with CUDA 6.5 on a machine with a GTX Titan card (compute capability 3.5). I'm building my code with just `-gencode=arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 -gencode=arch=compute_35,code=sm_35` - and when I link my binary, nvlink says:

```
nvlink warning : SM Arch ('sm_20') not found in '/local/eyalroz/src/foo/CMakeFiles/tester.dir/src/./tester_generated_main.cu.o'
```

Why is it warning me about that? Do I need `sm_20` for something I'm not aware of? If it's merely about the lack of lower compute capability support, why not `sm_10` as well? (Also, how do I turn off the warning, if it's gratuitous?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was identified in CUDA 6.5 and has been rectified I believe in CUDA 7.5.  Using the latest version of CUDA should make those warnings go away.

Comment: Not sure this is true: I'm on `release 7.5, V7.5.17` and I see the warning.

Answer (score 1):

Just ignore it

i'm on cuda RC8 and have the same issue:

nvlink warning : SM Arch ('sm_20') not found in 'cudainfo.o'

compile:
/usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc -g -O2  -Iyes/include -Iyes/include -I. -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 -rdc=true --ptxas-options=-v -I./compat/jansson  -o cudainfo.o -c cudainfo.cu

$ nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2016 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Wed_May__4_21:01:56_CDT_2016
Cuda compilation tools, release 8.0, V8.0.26

Comment: do you also get the deprecated sm_20 etc warning before the "not found" warning ?
I am having the same problem with cuda 8, the thing is that i have cmake in the mix so i am not sure if that is messing with something, i compiled with verbose mode and no where there is sm_20 etc defined, only the one i set sm_30 and sm_50 so i wanted to double check